# How to save SVN revision number automatically after each commit?

Tags: svn, webpack

I need to show SVN commit revision number in front-end, for example, `build 1790`
where build number should correspond to revision number from svn.

Is it possible that after each commit SVN automatically save revision number in a file?

Comment: It's really not clear what *front-end* and *save revision* (revision number?, changeset?) mean in your context. Do you want so kind of automated build on commit? Could you please expand on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Filburt I've edited. Is it clear now? revision number. yes, It's kind of automated build on commit.

Comment: Did you already look into [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)? This offers the most basic echoing of the revision number but is flexible enough to place it where needed. Depending on your build automation, there may be better Tasks/Plugins/etc. available.

Comment: @Filburt Yes, I've looked into it. It looks like the easiest solution. Should I edit this file every time when I commit something? 

I use webpack and there is not plugin for SVN.

Comment: You don't have to edit your files once you placed the `$Rev$` keyword - it will be updated automatically on checkout or export. I'm not familiar with webpack so I can't advise on automating things.

Comment: @Filburt thanks, but it doesn't update the file after each commit if this file isn't include in this commit. I have tested it.

Comment: You're right - you have to use [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) to extract the "global revision". It's been a while since a last used svn ...

Comment: @Filburt Thank you. I have done it using ``svnversion`` and It works fine with webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Filburt have suggested a solution to save [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) command output to a file.

I used webpack to do it.

```
plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
        onBuildEnd: ['svnversion --no-newline > ./dist/svn-revision-number.txt']
    })
]
```